# How to run polymer project on xampp

Tags: xampp, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

Hello I am building a web page from the Polymer starter kit and I started to use PHP there so now I need to run it on Xampp but how to do it the page doesn't load when I start it using Xampp

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the content of the polymer subdirectory `bundled` to the root directory of XAMPP, from which the HTML files are served. Open your browser on `localhost:/index.html`.

Polymer ist just HTML+JavaScript. No PHP needed.

Comment: Thank you. For your help